# Echo HTML with PHP in the middle

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and am running into a small problem with this code. I am trying to make a layout for a page that uses more PHP to fill in the blanks.

When I view the source `<? include $navbar ?>` is commented out but `<?=$pagetitle?>` works, why is that?

For reference:
`$navbar = "navbar.php";`
and `navbar.php`:

```
<?php echo "Select Car Change Profile"; ?>
```

Layout.php:

```
<?php
echo "
<html>
<head>
    <title>Race Data. <?=$pagetitle?></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='page'>
        <table border='1'>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='3'>Banner goes here.<?=$pagetitle?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan='2'>Left menu</td>
                    <td colspan='2'><? include $navbar; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content</td>
                    <td>Right menu</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='3'>Footer</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</html>
";
?>
```

I'm sure knowing this will help amny future problems I run into.

Also, what are the diferences in using `<? ?>` vs `<?php ?>`?

Comment: Do you have short tags enabled?

Comment: When you're inside `echo "Quotes"` you can always echo php variables by `echo "Quotes {$variable} or $variable";` or more convoluted by `echo "Quote " . $variable . " End Quote";`

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The only thing that isn't working is I can't get my echo from `navbar.php` to display inside of my echo in the `<td colspan='2'><?php include $navbar; ?></td>` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In php, you always need to use `<?php /*code*/ ?>`

The shorthand version to echo something is `<?= /*string*/ ?>`, but to run code, such as an `include` you would need to start with `<?php`. In your example, this would be:

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan='2'>Left menu</td>
    <td colspan='2'><?php include $navbar; ?></td>
</tr>
```

---

### Correction

I only just noticed that you placed the PHP tags inside another set of PHP tags. You're kind of doing it the hard way. In a PHP file, anything is regarded as an echo, except for content inside `<?php ?>` tags. So this should work perfectly for you:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Race Data. <?=$pagetitle?></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='page'>
        <table border='1'>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='3'>Banner goes here.<?=$pagetitle?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan='2'>Left menu</td>
                    <td colspan='2'><?php include $navbar; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content</td>
                    <td>Right menu</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='3'>Footer</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</html>
```

The difference is that I didn't put `<?php ?>` tags around the whole thing.

Comment: I guess the next question is can you use `<?php ?>` in an echo statement? or how would i go about doing that?

Comment: I wouldn't know that, actually. I'd assume it would work just fine, and print that onto the page. You'd have to try that for yourself to see though.

Comment: I had to break the echo statement:
To get it to work for the time being I changed it too `echo "<td colspan='2'>"; include $navbar; echo "</td>"` just to get it to work. There has to be a better way of doing this I am not sure. This is reflected above.

Comment: @rukamir please see my updated answer. If this doesn't work, please tell me, so I can check what's going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
short_open_tag=On;
```

in php.ini

And restart your Apache server.

Comment: just enabled it and nothing has changed.